# Creating a class that have multiple instances of another class in array?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to create a class A where one of its instance variables is an array consisting of objects of class B. Is it possible to access the method of class B through class A, so it possible to do something like:

```
classA.classB[0].getSth()
```

Or is there any other way to access the method in class B through class A?

Comment: You can access class B methods from class A if class B's access modifier allows. Please read through Java Access Modifiers

Answer (score 0):

So long as class `A` exposes `B[]` instance (with proper access modifiers or via getters), it is allowed in any OOP language (here, Java) to provide access in the way you have mentioned.

Look at the example below:

```
public class ObjectAcces {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B[] bs = {new B(1), new B(2), new B(3), new B(4)};
        A a = new A(bs);

        System.out.println("** Printing All Values **");
        a.printAll();

        System.out.println("** Printing Specific Value **");
        a.bs[0].print();
    }
}

class A {
    B[] bs;

    public A(B[] bs) {
        super();
        this.bs = bs;
    }

    void printAll() {
        Arrays.stream(bs).forEach(b -> b.print());
    }
}

class B {
    private int val;

    public B(int val) {
        super();
        this.val = val;
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("Val: " + val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. The most important thing to remember is the access modifiers. For you to be able to call `a.b[0]`, you must make `b` either package-private or public.

```
public class A {
  B[] b;
}

public class B {
  public void sayHi() {
    System.out.println();
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String...args) {
    A a = new A()
    B b1 = new B(), b2 = new B(), b3 = new B();
    a.b = {b1,b2,b3};
    a.b[0].sayHello();
  }
}
```